# How to store specific html table row value to arraylist in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an arrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have a table with different rows, each row has a value of user name as a string. I want to store that value from all rows into my array list.

HTML of the table is:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>
        <td class="left">
            <a href="saveSystemUser?userId=13">9090sdsd</a>
        </td>
        <td class="left">ESS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>
        <td class="left">
            <a href="saveSystemUser?userId=2">Abc123</a>
        </td>
        <td class="left">ESS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td/>
        <td class="left">
            <a href="saveSystemUser?userId=1">AdminOH</a>
        </td>
        <td class="left">Admin</td>
</tr>
```

I want to retrieve text of `<a href="">userName</a>` from each `tr` and store it in arrayList userNames.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to write your own HTML parser.
I assume your program gets the HTML code as a string.

How to parse HTML:
Start by writing a method to find the index of a given string, like
"❬tr" or "❬/tr". It would look like

```
private int parseTo(String findMe, String parseMe, int index)
```

which would march through parseMe, starting at index, until it finds the first letter of findMe. Then it marches through findMe, checking each letter findMe.charAt(n) against parseMe.charAt(index + n), and if they all match, returns index.

So you can use this to find the location of each ❬a❭ and matching ❬/a❭ tag. For each pair, when you have their locations, you can use parseMe.substring(beginIndex, endIndex) to get that section of string, then add it to the arrayList.
To do that, find each "❬a", then find the following "❭", to eschew the href="blablabla" nonsense. Store that index, + 1, to be the first int fed to your parseMe.substring() method. Then you find the matching "❬/a❭". Store that index - 1 as the second int for substring(). Add parseMe.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex) to the arrayList, and move on to the next "❬a" by starting at the second int you fed substring(), so that parseTo() will find the next user and not just the same one over and over again.

Some possible problems:

1. I'm pretty sure javac will recognize substring() and charAt(), but if not, put import java.lang.String; at the top.
2. If there are no more "❬a" substrings in parseMe, parseTo() won't stop until it exceeds the length of parseMe, and then you'll get an arrayOutOfBoundsException. That shouldn't be a problem if you know how many users to look for, but if you don't, have a method march through parseMe counting anchor tags.